# Как инициализировать звонок через SWIFT приложение на iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, framework

Нужно создать приложение, которое будет совершать звонок по заданному номеру при нажатии кнопки в приложении, написанного  на SWIFT.
К примеру в скорую помощь.
Опыта работы со Свифтом имею мало, потому не знаю как это реализовать.
Есть ли какие-то фреймворки которые позволяют это сделать или это можно решить стандартными средствами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать стандартные средства для этого. Пример функции для совершения звонка:

**Swift 2.3:**

```
func callForHelp(number: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(number)")!
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func callForHelp(_ number: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```